# How to determine the modulus of a Float in Ada 95

Tags: math, floating-point, ada

I need to determine the amount left of a time cycle. To do that in C I would use fmod. But in ada I can find no reference to a similar function. It needs to be accurate and it needs to return a float for precision.

So how do I determine the modulus of a Float in Ada 95?

```
 elapsed := time_taken mod 10.348;
 left := 10.348 - elapsed;
 delay Duration(left);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the floating point ['Remainder](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-5-3.html#I5529) attribute.

```
Elapsed, Time_Taken : Float;

...

Elapsed := Float'Remainder(Time_Taken, 10.348);
```

Comment: Be warned that Remainder will return negative numbers.
if Elapsed < 0 then
   Elapsed := 10.384 - Elapsed;
end if;

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer to your actual question; but, to achieve the intention of that piece of code, consider using [delay until](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-9-6.html#I3755).

```
   Next_Time : Ada.Calendar.Time;
   use type Ada.Calendar.Time;
   Period : constant Duration := 10.348;
begin
   ...
   Next_Time := Ada.Calendar.Clock;
   loop
      -- do stuff
      Next_Time := Next_Time + Period;
      delay until Next_Time;
   end loop;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Ada, but assuming it has a `Floor` function you could use `elapsed := time_taken - Floor(time_taken / 10.348) * 10.348)`.

Edit: I also just found [this](http://www.mofeel.net/842-comp-lang-ada/1883.aspx) discussion on using the Remainder attribute for this purpose.

Comment: Also note that I've assumed `time_taken` isn't going to be negative.

Comment: Ada has the floor Attribute; i.e Float'Floor.

e.g. Float'Floor(10.5) = 10.0